# Shell script to hold the log content and process it with other commands

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sh

I would like to get collective input on improving my data mining to reduce the process and time taken to tabulate the result. Currently the below process is working for me , but each time I trigger the extract_log is taking around 40 second for 1 awk process to the timing log under the xampp.

```
#!/bin/bash
//Total time to process is 2 minutes
extract_log=`awk -v d1=\"$(date --date=\"-5 min\" \"+%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S\")\" -v d2=\"$(date \"+%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S\")\" 'substr($4,2) > d1 && substr($4,2) < d2 || substr($4,2) ~ d2' /xampp/timing_log | awk  'substr($7,2,8) ~  /apollo/'  | grep -v 'x-frame'  | awk -F  '\"' '{print substr($3,1,4)}' | sort | uniq -c `
extract_log2=`awk -v d1=\"$(date --date=\"-5 min\" \"+%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S\")\" -v d2=\"$(date \"+%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S\")\" 'substr($4,2) > d1 && substr($4,2) < d2 || substr($4,2) ~ d2' /xampp/timing_log | awk  'substr($7,2,8) ~  /apollo/'  | grep -v 'session'  | awk -F  '\"' '{print substr($3,1,4)}' | sort | uniq -c `
extract_log3=`awk -v d1=\"$(date --date=\"-5 min\" \"+%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S\")\" -v d2=\"$(date \"+%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S\")\" 'substr($4,2) > d1 && substr($4,2) < d2 || substr($4,2) ~ d2' /xampp/timing_log | awk  'substr($7,2,8) ~  /apollo/'  | grep -v 'login'  | awk -F  '\"' '{print substr($3,1,4)}' | sort | uniq -c `

echo $extract_log
echo $extract_log2
echo $extract_log3
```

I was thinking is it possible to achieve like something below?

```
#!/bin/bash
//Have variable to store the logs from timing log previous 5 minutes

store_log=`awk -v d1=\"$(date --date=\"-5 min\" \"+%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S\")\" -v d2=\"$(date \"+%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S\")\" 'substr($4,2) > d1 && substr($4,2) < d2 || substr($4,2) ~ d2' /xampp/timing_log `

//Pipe it to $store_log and perform $extract_log to filter it?

extract_log=`$store_log | awk  'substr($7,2,8) ~  /apollo/'  | grep -v 'session'  | awk -F  '\"' '{print substr($3,1,4)}' | sort | uniq -c  `
extract_log2=`$store_log | awk  'substr($7,2,8) ~  /apollo/'  | grep -v 'x-frame'  | awk -F  '\"' '{print substr($3,1,4)}' | sort | uniq -c  `
extract_log3=`$store_log | awk  'substr($7,2,8) ~  /apollo/'  | grep -v 'login'  | awk -F  '\"' '{print substr($3,1,4)}' | sort | uniq -c  `

echo $extract_log
echo $extract_log2
echo $extract_log3
```

I'm having error trying it out, maybe i'm shallow on the concept. I need some enlighten from fellow Stackoverflow.

The example input of the logs are like the following :-

```
27.125.249.169 - - [21/Nov/2020:03:36:24 +0800] "GET /sites/all/modules/qk3rc2.js HTTP/1.1" 200 9749 " "3106"
27.125.250.251 - - [21/Nov/2020:03:36:27 +0800] "GET /sites/all/modules/qk3rc2.js HTTP/1.1" 200 7570  "2669"
27.125.242.71 - - [21/Nov/2020:03:36:30 +0800] "POST /apollo/forgotpin HTTP/1.1" 302 41737  "4017638"
175.137.6.253 - - [21/Nov/2020:03:36:35 +0800] "GET /sites/all/modules/qk3rc2.js HTTP/1.1" 200 7570  "2716"
27.125.242.71 - - [21/Nov/2020:03:36:35 +0800] "GET /apollo/forgot HTTP/1.1" 301  "2531839"
113.210.102.190 - - [21/Nov/2020:03:36:40 +0800] "GET /sites/all/modules/qk3rc2.js HTTP/1.1" 200 7570  "2823"
115.133.72.77 - - [21/Nov/2020:03:36:40 +0800] "GET /sites/all/modules/um_wsdl/oxi.wsdl HTTP/1.1" 200 7570  "2678"
27.125.242.71 - - [21/Nov/2020:03:36:37 +0800] "GET /apollo/forgot HTTP/1.1" 200 8730  "4223072"
```

The output :-

```
   1452  200
      5  206
     44  301
     20  302
     18  404
     29  500
     94  503
```

The result are the HTTP Code uniq count based on the apache traffic logs . I also have other AWK command to get the pattern based on url and extract the count for monitoring purpose.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: @Cyrus, thanks for highlighting it cyrus. Let me add it up

Comment: @Cyrus, added already . Is it suffice?

Comment: Is `The output` the output you want or the output you get that you don't want? Make sure to provide the expected output **from the sample input you post**. [edit] your question to describe how you want to transform the input to the output in terms of the text in your input/output (don't assume we know what `The result are the HTTP Code uniq count based on the apache traffic logs` means) so we can help you write an awk script to do that. Also tell us roughly how many lines long `/xampp/timing_log` would typically be.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do a date comparison with code like `substr($4,2) > d1` but you can't do a string comparison on 2 dates in the format `21/Nov/...` and `10/Dec/...` and expect to get a meaningful result since `1` being less than `2` will stop the comparison and say that `21/Nov` is larger then (later than) than `10/Dec`. You need to use timestamps like `2020/11/21` and `2020/12/10` or similar to be able to compare them.

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do but here's a good start based on my interpretation of your code:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk -v begDate="$(date --date='-5 min' '+%F:%T')" -v endDate="$(date '+%F:%T')" '
substr($7,2,6) != "apollo" { next }
{
    split($4,t,"[[/:]")
    monthNr = (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",t[3])+2)/3
    curDate = sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d",t[4],monthNr,t[2],t[5],t[6],t[7])

}
(curDate <= begDate) || (curDate > endDate) { next }
{
    code = $9
    codes[code]
}
!/session/ { extract_log[code]++ }
!/x-frame/ { extract_log2[code]++ }
!/login/   { extract_log3[code]++ }
END {
    for (code in codes) {
        print code, extract_log[code]+0, extract_log2[code]+0, extract_log3[code]+0
    }
}
' "${@:--}"
```

The above will work using any awk, run it as `tst.sh /xampp/timing_log`.

Comment: Thanks Ed, my motive is first pull last 5 minutes logs from awk, then break down further within that 5 minutes log for get multiple filter . But my current method with 5 different awk command, i'm opening the files every time i'm doing a search. So with this method, i'm able to store and perform recursive search?